# How to update time since chat comment in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on relative timestamp on chat messages and i want write time elapsed for every chat message .

example im fetching messages like that :

```
  while($row = $mess->fetch()){
      echo "<div class='chattime'>".$date."</div>";  //$date is 1469994973
  }
```

And it output this

```
<div class='chattime'>1469994973</div>
<div class='chattime'>1469997928</div>
<div class='chattime'>1469998219</div>
<div class='chattime'>1469998430</div>
```

Then i have this function and i want to update this timestamp as

2s , 5s ago , 2minutes ago , and so on for every message .Every  5 seconds it updates how much time ago .

But it didnt update anything i dont know what im doing wrong , here my javascript

```
function timeDifference(current, previous) {

    var msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
    var msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;
    var msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;
    var msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
    var msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;

    var elapsed = current - previous;

    if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {
        return Math.round(elapsed / 1000) + ' seconds ago';
    } else if (elapsed < msPerHour) {
        return Math.round(elapsed / msPerMinute) + ' minutes ago';
    } else if (elapsed < msPerDay) {
        return Math.round(elapsed / msPerHour) + ' hours ago';
    } else if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {
        return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerDay) + ' days ago';
    } else if (elapsed < msPerYear) {
        return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerMonth) + ' months ago';
    } else {
        return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerYear) + ' years ago';
    }
    $('.chattime').text(elapsed);
}
var chattime = $('.chattime').text();
var now = new Date(),
    current = now.getTime() / 1000;

setInterval(function () {
    timeDifference(current, chattime);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: well... your code is written in such a way that would only support a single .chattime element.

Comment: This is quite a mess. I suggest you keep the original time for each `div` in an attribute within the `<div>` tag. As it is, you're going to overwrite it the first time. Further, as mentioned above, you're not looping through the `div`s.

Comment: @JonathanM whats wrong in my code pls .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
<div class='chattime'>1469994973</div>
<div class='chattime'>1469997928</div>
<div class='chattime'>1469998219</div>
<div class='chattime'>1469998430</div>
```

Do this so you don't lose the initial value:

```
<div class='chattime' data-initial-value="1469994973"></div>
<div class='chattime' data-initial-value="1469997928"></div>
<div class='chattime' data-initial-value="1469998219"></div>
<div class='chattime' data-initial-value="1469998430"></div>
```

Change this function like so:

```
function timeDifference(current, previous) {

    var msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
    var msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;
    var msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;
    var msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
    var msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;

    var elapsed = current - previous;

    if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {
        return Math.round(elapsed / 1000) + ' seconds ago';
    } else if (elapsed < msPerHour) {
        return Math.round(elapsed / msPerMinute) + ' minutes ago';
    } else if (elapsed < msPerDay) {
        return Math.round(elapsed / msPerHour) + ' hours ago';
    } else if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {
        return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerDay) + ' days ago';
    } else if (elapsed < msPerYear) {
        return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerMonth) + ' months ago';
    } else {
        return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed / msPerYear) + ' years ago';
    }
}
```

And then do this to update the div values:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.chattime').each(function() {
        $(this).text(timeDifference(Date.now(), $(this).data('initial-value') * 1000));
    });
}, 5000);
```

Notice I'm using `$(selector).each()` to iterate through the divs. Here's the docs on that: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Here's a fiddle to show it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/pnaozpza/

Comment: this looks to be looping But it said 47 years ago i dont know why . the data i have is `1470168334`  is something wrong ? because the data i have is maybe yesterday only .

Comment: The fiddle works. Compare it to what you've put in. Be sure to get the line that multiplies the initial-value by 1000